# Calculate $ \lim_{x \to 1^{+}} \frac{x-1- \ln x }{(\ln x) (x-1)}$

Tags: real-analysis

My try:
 Firstly I tried to use basic property of limits. However then  I have $\frac{0}{0}$ and I don't know what I can do to get rid of division by $ 0 $.
That is why I wanted to use L'Hôpital's rule. So I have:
 $$\lim_{x \to 1^{+}}  \frac{x-1- \ln x }{\ln x (x-1)}=\lim_{x \to 1^{+}}  \frac{1-\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x}(x-1)+\ln x}=\frac{0}{0}$$
As you can see, this idea also did not work and I have no idea how to go about it. Can he help me with this task or indicate some error in reasoning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just apply L'Hopital's Rule one more time and you will get the answer.